# Transfer Firebase Storage Bucket between projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to copy the contents of a folder in one Firebase project's Storage bucket to the storage bucket of another Firebase project.

I have been following the firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173698/firestore-and-storage-bucket-export-import-between-projects).

Both projects have the necessary permissions to other's service accounts.

Here is what I have done:

When attempting to transfer files from a folder in the default bucket of Project-A to the default bucket of Project-B using the cloud shell terminal, I first set the project to 'Project-A'. I then ran `gcloud beta firestore export gs://[PROJECT_A_ID] --collection-ids=[FOLDER_TO_TRANSFER] --async`. This succeeds and creates a folder called "2019-08-26T21:23:23_26014/" in Project-A. This folder contains some metadata. 
Next, I tried beginning the import by setting the project to Project-B and running `gcloud beta firestore import gs://[PROJECT_A_ID]/2019-08-26T21:23:23_26014`
This completes and the logs display this message:

`done: true
metadata:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.admin.v1beta1.ImportDocumentsMetadata
  collectionIds:
  - [FOLDER_TO_TRANSFER]
  endTime: '2019-08-26T21:25:56.794588Z'
  inputUriPrefix: gs://[PROJECT_A_ID]/2019-08-26T21:23:23_26014
  operationState: SUCCESSFUL
  startTime: '2019-08-26T21:25:19.689430Z'
name: projects/[PROJECT_B]/databases/(default)/operations/[SOME_ID_STRING]
response:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Empty`

However, the Project-B storage bucket doesn't have any new files or folders. It looks like the import did nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to move Cloud Storage objects or Cloud Firestore data? The docs/commands you describe are the ones for moving Cloud Firestore data. If you're trying to move Cloud Storage objects, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects.

Comment: Ah, I am trying to move a folder within a Storage bucket. So I guess that'd be a storage object. The documentation doesn't seem to mention moving an object between projects though. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a transfer job in the GCP Console. You can specify source/destination buckets from different projects as long as you have access permissions. You can specify the folder by setting "Specify file filters":

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer

You can also use the [`gsutil` tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), which is part of `gcloud`, to move or copy your objects to another bucket.

So your default buckets would be `gs://[PROJECT_A_ID].appspot.com` and `gs://[PROJECT_B_ID].appspot.com` Let's say you wanted to copy over the contents of `my_directory`:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://[PROJECT_A_ID].appspot.com/my_directory gs://[PROJECT_B_ID].appspot.com
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. Do you happen to know what access permissions are needed to do the transfer? In the GCP Console, when I browse the buckets I only see buckets associated with the current project.

Comment: You may have to manually type in the bucket name if it's outside   your project. If you're the owner of both projects, you should have access.